# How to remove some prefix from download file path. e.g. http://localhost:XXXX/section-name"

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-redux, react-bootstrap

My web app is running on http://localhost:XXXX port number. In that one section, I want to download some files. but it will prefix "http://localhost:XXXX/section_name" in the path of the download file.

```
<a href={file_path} download={file_name}>
   <Button variant={"link"}>
      <b>Download File</b>
   </Button>
</a>
```

In the above code, I want to download pdf files. but at click time, it will convert path in the below format.

```
http://localhost:XXXX/section_name/file_path
```

I want to remove the "http://localhost:XXXX/section_name" part form download URL.

Comment: So you just need the file_path?

Comment: I get "http://localhost:XXXX/section_name/file_path". But I want only file_path.

Answer (score 0):

If you are confirmed that your `file_path` name will not contain `/` then you can just slice the url i.e

```
file_path.slice(file_path.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, file_path.length);
```